# dead ssd drive on zfs points to initramfs

Tags: linux, debian, zfs, initramfs

I have an ssd drive with failed controller and which was a part of a mirrored zfs vdev.
Now it boots into initramfs and says that it can't import pool "rpool".
when i issue

```
zpool import -f rpool
```

it says that there's no such pool or dataset.
However, in "zpool import" can see that rpool has status UNAVAIL because of insufficient replicas.
i would like to replace the dead drive with a new one.
I have tried:

```
1) zpool replace
2) zpool offline
3) zpool detach
```

and everytime i get that there's no such pool or dataset.
The only way i got it working was by importing as read only by using:

```
echo "1" | sudo tee /sys/module/zfs/parameters/zfs_max_missing_tvds
zpool import -o readonly=on rpool
```

output of zpool import as a screenshot: https://prnt.sc/91X8xc3vG1SA
I have it mounted as read-only and the zpool status output is: https://prnt.sc/vKzNL0nUFALc

Mounting as read-only boots into the OS.
However since it's mounted as readonly i can't actually make any changes to the pool like replacing the damaged drive.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you try to backup the information, destroy the pool and recreate it?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Unfortunately i don't have backups of the pool :(

Comment: As I read you can import it as r/o which is enough to make backup

Comment: @RomeoNinov i actually haven't thought about it until now.  I guess you're right, i could restore from it. Isn't there a much easier option like just replacing the faulty drive? What is the meaning of having a mirrored pool if i can't just replace the drive? it should be an easy process, like using mdadm.

Comment: `mdadm` is not about ZFS. And this is root filesystem so it's not so sample (especially on PC hardware)

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try to use original Solaris (live CD) and not install but try to manage the pool.

Comment: Where's the second device from a mirror ? Unless there's no second device (means you now have non-redundant pool) all you can do is to accept the loss of data.

Comment: @drookie the pool consists of 2 mirrored devices. there shouldnt be any data loss.

Comment: I don't see any `zpool status` output, only some vague stories. Doubt there's even a pool.

Comment: @drookie i have added a screenshot in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rpool` is merely a span. I don't see a mirror configuration at all (by the way it should be marked as `UNAVAIL`, I don't understand why it's `DEGRADED`, but you are probably running some old zfs version). Accept the loss of data, apreciate the experience. Two other pools are unaffected.

Comment: Thank you forinvesting your time in this, i really appreciate it. if i mount it as read-only it boots the OS and all files are intact. please checkout screenshot: https://prnt.sc/vKzNL0nUFALc

Comment: I guess i didn't want to accept the inevitable. Thank you for clarifying. i appreciate it.